# Subtracting one list from another in Python

Tags: python, list

**What I want to happen:** When given two lists (list a and list b), remove the numbers in list a that are in list b.

**What currently happens:** My first function works only if list a has only one number to be removed.

**What I've tried:** Turning the lists into sets, then subtracting a - b

```
def array_diff(a, b):
  c = list(set(a) - set(b))
  return c
```

**Also tried:** Turning the list into sets, looking for n in a and m in b, then if n = m to remove n.

```
def array_diff(a, b):
  list(set(a))
  list(set(b))
  for n in (a): 
    for m in (b):
      if n == m:
        n.remove()

        return a
```

**Possibly thought about:** Using the "not in" function to determine if something is in b or not.

**Sample Input/Output:**

INPUT: array_diff([1,2], [1]) OUTPUT: [2]

INPUT: array_diff([1,2,2], [1]) OUTPUT: [2] (This should come out to be [2,2]

Comment: Can't you just loop over 1 list and remove from the other?

Comment: Look at the duplicate. Ultimately you just alter the condition you want for your list comparison. But there are several examples of what you are trying to do throughout StackOverflow.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Just use it like that :

```
 c = [x for x in a if x not in b]
```